# Gas valve shuts off when blower starts

Tags: hvac

I’ve replaced basically everything but the box.
Everything works.  However the it flames up for maybe 3 or so seconds and as soon as the board clicks the blower on the gas valve shuts and flames go out.  I’m at a loss here as to the problem.  Even have had an Hvac guy help check it.
The transformer is new as well.  It is 93% unit Goodman. No pilot light.  Flame sensor, igniter, transformer, board, inducer, pressure switch all new.  Even hi limit.  Have even bypassed sensors to see if that was it.

Comment: Basically everything but what "box"? What model? How can "everything work" if it doesn't work?

Comment: If almost everything is new and still does not work, it sounds like something is mis-wired or have wires crossed somewhere, maybe even two wires shorting when the blower comes on.  Imagine the gas valve needs power to be on/open, high resistance in a wire might drop enough power to close the valve, when the blower is on.  This is more difficult to find than a broken/ non working piece/device.

Comment: Sounds like flame roll over sensor typically the board flashes lights and gives an error code indicating the problem.

Comment: or could be the thermocouple?